# Define Logging Based on packages using BasicConfigurator

Tags: log4j

I am trying to figure out how to seperate my log files based on the packages using BasicConfigurator
Like in my log4j.properties I used to have appenders like

```
log4j.logger.com.cambiahealth.engine.common.aspect=,memberservices
log4j.logger.com.cambiahealth.engine.rest.family=,familyservice
```

I tried the following but doesnt seem to seperate out the requests going to a particular file

FileAppender fa = new FileAppender();

```
fa.setName("abc");
fa.setFile("/usr/regence/mylog.log");
fa.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"));
fa.setThreshold(Level.INFO);
fa.setAppend(true);
fa.activateOptions();
BasicConfigurator.configure(fa);
System.out.println("The logger abc is initialized");
```

Logger log= Logger.getLogger("com.cambiahealth.engine.rest.family");
    log.addAppender(fa);

```
FileAppender xyz= new FileAppender();

xyz.setName("claims");
xyz.setFile("/usr/regence/myClaims.log");
xyz.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"));
xyz.setThreshold(Level.INFO);
xyz.setAppend(true);
xyz.activateOptions();
BasicConfigurator.configure(claims);
System.out.println("The logger xyz is initialized");
BasicConfigurator.configure(xyz);
Logger.getLogger("com.xyz.claim").addAppender(xyz);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to removed the basicConfigurator.Configure out! and it all works now